# 2 checkboxes with same behavior

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

i have 2 identic checkboxes in my form. One in the top-area ('#locked1'), one in the bottom-area ('#locked2'). They are doing the same and should behave the same. Means if i uncheck the top checkbox the bottom-checkbox should also get unchecked.
I've build a working solution but i don't like it. It is an easy task and should not need that much lines of code. But i don't have a better idea. Maybe you do?

```
$('#locked1').change(function () {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $('#locked2').prop('checked', true);
            } else {
                $('#locked2').prop('checked', false);
            }
        });

        $('#locked2').change(function () {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                $('#locked1').prop('checked', true);
            } else {
                $('#locked1').prop('checked', false);
            }
        });
```

Comment: You can minimize every function to one line: ' $('#locked2').prop('checked', $(this).is(":checked"));'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$('#locked1,#locked2').change(function(){
   $('#locked1,#locked2').prop('checked', $(this).is(":checked"));
});
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/nodiqepo/1/edit)

Answer (score 4):

either you could change it to classes and target all the checkboxes or find both #locked1 and #locked2 and check on the change event and take whatever `checked`-value the checkbox you changed value is:

```
var checkboxes = $("#locked1, #locked2");

checkboxes.change(function() {
    checkboxes.prop("checked", this.checked);
});
```

Comment: This is the correct solution, no duplicate jquery calls and unnecessary jquery object to check the state of the checkbox. Understanding contexts ftw! =)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could always do something like this:

```
$("#locked1").changed(function() {
    $("#locked2").prop("checked", $(this).is(":checked"));
}

$("#locked2").changed(function() {
    $("#locked1").prop("checked", $(this).is(":checked"));
}
```

Edited: voigtan's answer is a more succinct solution than mine.  Although, be careful using .checked as I've had problems with this in the past.

Comment: when you use the `change` event it will get the current checked value, have never had any problems with it with the `change` event.

Answer (score 0):

Much the same answer as others have suggested, but you can combine them together into a single  function for ease of maintenance.

```
$('input[id^=locked]').on("click",function () {
    $('input[id^=locked]').prop('checked', $(this).is(":checked"));
});
```

Would be slightly simpler if the two inputs had a shared class to select them by. but this works.